# Register-Environment Failing

Tags: azure-devops

I am having trouble creating a release definition on Azure DevOps. I believe the Register-Environment function in PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1 is failing:

```
try
{
    $connection = Get-VssConnection -TaskContext $distributedTaskContext

    Write-Verbose "Starting Register-Environment cmdlet call for environment : $environmentName with filter $machineFilter"
    $environment = Register-Environment -EnvironmentName $environmentName -EnvironmentSpecification $environmentName -UserName $adminUserName -Password $adminPassword -WinRmProtocol $protocol -TestCertificate ($testCertificate -eq "true") -Connection $connection -TaskContext $distributedTaskContext -ResourceFilter $machineFilter
    Write-Verbose "Completed Register-Environment cmdlet call for environment : $environmentName"

    Write-Verbose "Starting Get-EnvironmentResources cmdlet call on environment name: $environmentName"
    $resources = Get-EnvironmentResources -Environment $environment

    if ($resources.Count -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Telemetry "Input_Validation" "No machine exists for given environment"
        throw (Get-LocalizedString -Key "No machine exists under environment: '{0}' for deployment" -ArgumentList $environmentName)
    }

    $resourcesPropertyBag = Get-ResourcesProperties -resources $resources
}
```

With the following error (I have omitted some of my organization's information, but it is there and looks right):

```
2019-09-04T12:34:55.6886629Z ##[debug]VssConnection created
2019-09-04T12:34:55.7518340Z ##[debug]Starting Register-Environment cmdlet call for environment : [machine] with filter [machine]
2019-09-04T12:34:55.7843531Z ##[debug]Begin Create-Environment cmdlet
2019-09-04T12:34:55.7872731Z ##[debug]UserName=[username]
2019-09-04T12:34:55.7878292Z ##[debug]WinRmProtocol=HTTP
2019-09-04T12:34:55.7878658Z ##[debug]TestCertificate=False
2019-09-04T12:34:55.7878965Z ##[debug]Unable to create a environment object for given json - Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: A. Path '', line 0, position 0.
2019-09-04T12:34:55.7879241Z ##[debug]projectName=[projectName]
2019-09-04T12:34:55.7879517Z ##[debug]Getting environment [machine] from DTL Service
2019-09-04T12:34:55.8485808Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;code={"Task_Internal_Error":Page not found.};]
```

And I do not know what to do. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Agree with you. This issue should caused by your Register-Environment function. The command should doesn't match your function JSON structure. But, you didn't share the details of this function, we could analysis it. You'd better update the question with your code of this function.

Comment: Hey Merlin, thanks for taking a look and posting a comment. Register-Environment actually comes from a Microsoft PowerShell module and I do not have the code for it. I posted a question in search of the latest version of this Microsoft PowerShell module here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891638/how-to-get-latest-version-of-microsoft-teamfoundation-distributedtask-task-deplo, but now I'm using V3 of the azure-pipeline-tasks PowerShellOnTargetMachines which doesn't use Register-Environment.

Comment: Aha,according to these tickets you raised in SO and DC, I seemed got what issue you are facing. For correct answer, I need to confirm something with you first . 1. Which version task are you using in this ticket? I assume you are using 3.* and want to executing the script which you provided in the question, right? 2. Why you want to execute these script in PowershellOnTargetMachines 3.*? In one word, what do you want to do with this task?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the details which from comment that Mike left, the issue should caused by the the task version you are using and its feature script we defined.

According to the ticket description you raised in [DC ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/731361/where-to-download-latest-versions-of-deployment-ut.html):

> I am trying to use V2 of the following 'PowerShellOnTargetMachines'
>   PowerShell script for a release on azure devops, from
>   azure-pipeline-tasks.

the version of PowerShellOnTargetMachines you are using is 2.*.

We can get the `Register-Environment` cmdlet script with decompile tool follow the method I showed in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891638/how-to-get-latest-version-of-microsoft-teamfoundation-distributedtask-task-deplo/58056824#58056824).

[image]

You can see the parameters this cmdlet supported in 'PowerShellOnTargetMachines V2.*' does not include **TaskContext** and **Connection**. That's why you receive the error message `"Unable to create a environment object for given json - Unexpected character encountered while parsing value"`. Because the parameter you input in the task does not match the configuration of `Register-Environment` cmdlet.

---

You can try with `PowerShellOnTargetMachines V1.*`. In `1.*` we support the parameters **TaskContext** and **Connection**.