# How to get latest version of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Deployment.dll?

Tags: azure-devops

Where can I download the latest version of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Deployment.dll for a release on Azure DevOps?

Comment: Hi, what’s your issue progress? Does the decompiled script could solve your puzzle? Feel free to leave comment if you still need help or still had issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent) are regularly updated to make sure the latest and applicable images of the softwares are applied to the agents.

If you want to use the latest version of softwares to run the related pipeline tasks on DevOps,you can install the latest softwares on the agents which you used .

If the agent you used is privated agent, you need to manually install or upgrade all the softwares you request on the agent machine.By downloading the latest package from Internet or using the related commands to install/upgrade the softwares.

You can refer to this  [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/731361/where-to-download-latest-versions-of-deployment-ut.html) for details.

Comment: Hi, that's actually my question. Thanks for taking a look. I've posted a comment on the answer there with a little bit more detail.

Comment: Hi,Mike our engineers need more information to investigate further in the dc forum,you can continue it.

Answer (score 0):

*For other SO users could get clearly know more details about this issue when they are checking to this ticket, I add the following ticket which relevant with this ticket:*

SO forum: [Register-Environment Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791676/register-environment-failing?noredirect=1)

DC forum: [Where to download latest versions of deployment utilities for azure pipeline tasks?](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/731361/where-to-download-latest-versions-of-deployment-ut.html)

---

When you using the task(such as `AzureFileCopy V1.*`) which need/import the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Deployment.dll` file, no matter whether the agent you used is hosted agent or private agent, its version are always be the **latest** version to the task, because these dll files are all exists depend with task.

---

According to the content you shared in the DC forum [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/731361/where-to-download-latest-versions-of-deployment-ut.html):

> I suspect that there's a newer version of these with a newer version
>   of Register-Environment, because with my version of this PowerShell
>   module, the following line fails claiming that I'm missing parameters,
>   specifically a "taskContext."

the error you are facing caused by the configuration of the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Deployment.dll` file. We did not defined the parameter `taskContext` in it.

To check and verify it, you can execute the `PowerShellOnTargetMachines v2.*` task in your private agent, then find the `dll` file in the path of `~\_work\_tasks\PowerShellOnTargetMachines_3b5693d4-5777-4fee-862a-bd2b7a374c68\2.0.7\DeploymentUtilities`. And also, you can see its version is `16.0.0.0`.

Then you can use decompile tool, here what I am using is **Reflector**, to decompile this `dll` file.

[image]

You can see that in the script block of `RegisterEnvironmentCmdlet`, there does not have parameter `taskContext` defined in it.

When you use `PowerShellOnTargetMachines v2.*` task, the parameter for `Register-Environment` supported only include `EnvironmentName`, `EnvironmentSpecification`, `UserName`, `Password`, `WinRmProtocol`, `TestCertificate`, `ResourceFilter`, `ProjectName`, `TagsList`.

For the parameter `taskContext`, it is the one which only used in `v1.*`(See [v1.* source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PowerShellOnTargetMachinesV1/PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1)) and does not supported in `v2.*`. In v1.*, `taskContext` used for `Get-VssConnection` cmdlet which dose not used any more in `v2.*`. That's why you facing the error message in `PowerShellOnTargetMachines v2.*` task.